# Find the maximum number of nodes on the same level in a binary tree (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

Lets define a binary tree structure as a set of nodes and the tree itself is:

- Is empty or,
- Consists of root node and left and right binary sub-tree
  nodes

So relaying on the mentioned definition we can represent binary trees in Prolog with the set of terms which satisfy the following `binaryTree` predicate.

```
binaryTree(nil):- !.
binaryTree(bTree(L, _, R)):- binaryTree(L), binaryTree(R).
```

For example, the following b tree

[image]

corresponds structure:

```
bTree(bTree(nil, b, nil), a, bTree(bTree(nil, d, nil), c, nil))
```

My questions is about how to find the length of the given binary tree, i.e. the maximum number of nodes on the same level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (have not done much test to verify correctness, that is up to you):

```
binaryTree(nil):- !.
binaryTree(bTree(L, _, R)):- binaryTree(L), binaryTree(R).

max_length(T, Max):-
    traverse(T, 0, Ts),
    get_levels(Ts, Levels),
    sort(0, @=<, Levels, Levels1),
    get_max_length(Levels1, _, 0, 0, Max).

traverse(bTree(L,V,R), Level, bTree(L1, V, R1, Level)):-
    Level1 is Level + 1,
    traverse(L, Level1, L1),
    traverse(R, Level1, R1).

traverse(nil, _, nil).

get_levels(nil, []).

get_levels(bTree(L,_,R, Lev), [Lev|Levs2]):-
    get_levels(L, Levs0),
    get_levels(R, Levs1),
    append(Levs0,Levs1,Levs2).

get_max_length([], _, Acc,Max0, Max1):-
    (Acc > Max0 ->
     Max1 is Acc;     
     Max1 is Max0
    ).

get_max_length([Curr|T], Curr, Acc, Max0, Max1):-
    Acc1 is Acc + 1,
    get_max_length(T, Curr, Acc1, Max0, Max1).

get_max_length([X|T], Curr, Acc, Max0, Max1):-
    \+ X = Curr,
    (Acc > Max0 ->
     get_max_length(T, X, 1, Acc, Max1);     
     get_max_length(T, X, 1, Max0, Max1)
    ).
```

2 test cases, first the tree in your picture and then this tree:

```
                                                   +-----+
                                                  -+-----+---
                                              ---/           \-----
                                   +------+--/                     \+------+
                                 --+------+                         ++-----+---
                               -/         |                          |         \---
                       +-----+/           +------+          +-------/              \+------+
                       /-----\            /------\          /-------\               +/-----+-
                     -/       \         -/        \       -/         \-            -/        \---
                   -/         |       -/          |     -/             \         -/              \--
            +-----/     +------\    +/----+   +----\  +/----+    +------\       /------+      +-----\-
            +-----+     +------+    +-----+   +----+  +-----+    +------+       +------+      +-----+
```

Add the following to the code and run with `test.`

```
test:-
    T0 = bTree(bTree(nil, b, nil), a, bTree(bTree(nil, d, nil), c, nil)),
    max_length(T0, 2),
    T1 = bTree(
               bTree(
                     bTree(
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 3,
                                 nil
                                ),
                           2,
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 4,
                                 nil
                                )
                          ),
                     1,
                     bTree(
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 6,
                                 nil
                                ),
                           5,
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 7,
                                 nil
                                )
                          )
                    ),
               0,
               bTree(
                     bTree(
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 10,
                                 nil
                                ),
                           9,
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 11,
                                 nil
                                )
                          ),
                     8,
                     bTree(
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 13,
                                 nil
                                ),
                           12,
                           bTree(
                                 nil,
                                 14,
                                 nil
                                )
                          )
                    )),
    max_length(T1, 8).
```